# Can PowerBI Pro handle a very large (17GB) csv file?

Tags: powerbi

I have never used PowerBI before but am interested. If using PowerBI's Pro option (free trial), will I be able to work with a 17GB .csv file of some ~300 million rows? If not, what are my options for compressing it to make it possible to work with?

Thanks!

Comment: The desktop app or the online service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things to consider.  Generally, when judging the size of your final .pbix file, size of data sources are generally less of a concern as is their composition.  However, 17GB csv does sound pretty huge.

The file size is less of a concern because PowerBI has a pretty fantastic compression algorithm.  If your data source is full of repeating values, (we call this 'low cardinality'), then you will probably be surprised at how much it can be compressed.  However, if those 300 million rows are very unique, especially if it contains free-form text, then you will not get nearly as much benefit of compression.

Also, the huge number of rows may also impact the effectiveness of compression.  If there's anything that can be done to reduce the row count it's probably worthwhile -- perhaps reduced granularity, or chaptered reports.

When just working on your desktop, what ultimately matters is two things.  (1) how much memory (RAM) does your machine have, and (2) how big is your data set.  If your memory can hold the dataset without thrashing (constantly trading memory with disk space), all is well.  But, if PowerBI desktop has to go to virtual memory and write to disk, it will perform very badly.

But when you try to publish to service, even with a Pro License, a single PBIX file is limited to 1GB (you can have a total of 10GB saved under one account, but an individual file is limited to 1GB).  You might actually be able to publish it, but you will not be able to refresh the data online.  A 17:1 ratio is probably pushing it.

Some things that can really help loading a file like that:

1. exclude high cardinality, free-form text fields.
2. consider rounding high-precision values
3. break apart 'composite' fields -- e.g. convert time stamps to hours, minutes, seconds.  (reduces cardinality)

Answer (score 1):

The compressed filesize limit for [Power BI Pro accounts is 1GB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-manage-your-data-storage-in-power-bi#dataset-limits).

The first thing to do is just import the data to Power BI Desktop and save a pbix. Check the size of the file. It is within the realm of possibility that Power BI's compression will bring this down below 1GB. It is impossible to say how likely without knowing about the data in the CSV.

That being said, there are also plenty of size optimizations you can take on after loading the full file.

The easiest is to remove columns which you are not going to use. After that, you're likely to see some benefits from dimensionalizing the model.

After that, take a read [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/checklist-for-memory-optimizations-in-powerpivot-and-tabular-models/) and [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/optimizing-high-cardinality-columns-in-vertipaq/).

Answer (score 0):

I certainly agree with the answers by [Ryan B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1357061/ryan-b) and [greggyb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4382919/greggyb) above in regards to removing columns you are not going to use in your end report and seeing what PowerBI can do do with its built-in compression algorithms.  There shouldn't be any problem with importing the dataset, no matter how large, though expect a long delay in fetching all records.

However, I suggest analyzing your data to see if all 300 million rows *really* need to be updated regularly.  Are all of these records changing?  If not, you can split your main data table into several sources that do not require regular updating, essentially creating a model with incremental refresh by building your current dataset sourcing static data alongside your dynamic data.  This method will not only run faster as static models do not need to be refreshed, but make your report much easier to work with.